# Rename column name with hyphen (-) in laravel migration

Tags: php, laravel, database-migration

I'm trying to run a laravel migration that renames a particular column in my database but I repeatedly get an error message.

```
class ModifyColumnName extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->renameColumn("content-description", "content_description");
        });
    }

}
```

I keep on getting this error message.

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '-description content_description VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL' at line 1 (SQL: ALTER TABLE posts CHANGE content-description content_description VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL)
```

Comment: Never seen a database column name with a hyphen.

Comment: it is not good, but it is possible

Answer (score 3):

Put your column name with hyphen in backticks

```
Schema::table('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->renameColumn("`content-description`", "content_description");
});
```

Comment: These are backticks

Answer (score 1):

Hyphens in database names aren't good and hyphens are a big problem because if you end up mapping a column name to a variable, most languages do not like to have hyphens inside variable names.

But you can use them with the back-tick trick just enclose the column name within back-ticks(`)

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->renameColumn("`content-description`", "content_description");
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

since the column has no data, try this...

```
class ModifyColumnName extends Migration
{
 /**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->dropColumn("`content-description`");
        $table->string("`content_description`");
    });
}
/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::table('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->string("`content-description`");
        $table->dropColumn("`content_description"`);
    });
}
```

}

According to mariadb.com: "*Identifiers may be quoted using the backtick character -`. Quoting is optional for identifiers that do not contain special characters, or for identifiers that are not reserved words, if the ANSI_QUOTES SQL_MODE flag is set, double quotes ( ") can also be used to quote identifiers.*"

that's why I prefer innoDB ... !! to always use single quotes